# Invalid regular expression: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Tags: python, regex

Regex pattern used:

```
(?<!cart .*)(?<!order .)(\b\d{4,12}\b)
```

Examples:

```
so the cart number is 12344567 that it
my cart number is 1234
order number note down 12345
order 12345
credit card is 0000
4444
the 5456
```

Expected output:

```
0000
4444
5456
```

Here **i don't** want number that starts with word **`order` or `cart`** that can range from `4` to `12`.

Comment: Yes, you'd need [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to support that. A workaround can be [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and using a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) either like [this](https://regex101.com/r/07Zdd5/1) or [that](https://regex101.com/r/6BL0dx/1) or some [other trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Python with a infinite quantifier in the lookbehind, you can use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

You don't need the capture group, and you have to repeat the dot for the order part `(?<!order .*)`

But using an alternation, you can use a single lookbehind:

```
(?<!(?:cart|order) .*)\b\d{4,12}\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYM5AG/1).

Example

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?<!(?:cart|order) .*)\b\d{4,12}\b"

s = ("so the cart number is 12344567 that it\n\n"
    "my cart number is 1234\n\n"
    "order number note down 12345\n\n"
    "order 12345\n\n"
    "credit card is 0000\n\n"
    "4444\n\n"
    "the 5456")

print(regex.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['0000', '4444', '5456']
```

---

Another option is to use an alternation with *re.findall* and filter out the empty values, or use *re.finditer* and loop the values checking for a group 1 value.

An example with re.findall, where you match what you don't want and capture in group 1 what you want to keep using a for comprehension:

```
import re

pattern = r"^.*\b(?:cart|order)\b.*|(\b\d{4,12}\b)"

s = ("so the cart number is 12344567 that it\n"
            "my cart number is 1234\n"
            "order number note down 12345\n"
            "order 12345\n"
            "credit card is 0000\n"
            "4444\n"
            "the 5456")

print([s for s in re.findall(pattern, s, re.M) if s])
```

Output

```
['0000', '4444', '5456']
```

Comment: Any other alternative ways is there other than PY regex?

Comment: @Dip I have added another solution with Python `re`

Comment: i have code i want number not starting with order and card as well as it should not end with dollar also
can we acheive expected output by passing one example at a time using re module 
import re

pattern = "(^.*\b(?:cart|order)\b.*)(\b\d{2,12}\b)"

text1 = ('the cart number is 1234 and 4567 that it!')
text2 = ("order number note down 12345")
text3 = "credit card is 0000"
text4 = "the 4567"
text5 = "i got 245 dollar"


result = re.search(pattern, text4)

print(result)
Expected output match
text3 0000
text4 4567

Comment: @Dip If you want to do that with re.search and get a single match, then you can do it like this https://ideone.com/ynXr8M

Comment: Hi Actually i dont want to match number followed by words dollar or points as well. I tried with your provide code in re.findall() but i am facing issue. Can you help me on this. Thank you

Comment: import re

pattern = r"^.*\b(?:cart|order)\b.*|(\b\d{4,12}\b)"

s = ("so the cart number is 12344567 that it\n"
            "my cart number is 1234\n"
            "order number note down 12345\n"
            "order 12345\n"
            "credit card is 0000\n"
            "4444 dollar\n"
            "the 5456")

print([s for s in re.findall(pattern, s, re.M) if s])

Comment: @Dip The pattern also matches those digits. Can you give an example what exactly you want to match and what is giving you an issue? Please create a  regex101 example link with what should and should not be matched.

Comment: Hi i am matching number that doesnot start with words cart or order. And also number that doesnot end with dollar and points.


import re

pattern = r"^.*\b(?:cart|order)\b.*|(\b\d{4,12}\b)"

text1 = 'the cart number is 1234 and 4567 that it!'

text2 = "order 12345"

text3 = "credit card is 0000 4567 and 3456"

text4 = "i got 245 dollar"

text5 = "the 4567 and 2345 "


for s in re.findall(pattern, text2, re.M):

    if s:

        print(s)

Expected output for each text example

text1  None

text2  None

text3  0000 4567 3456

text4  None

text5  4567 2345

Comment: is it possible with use of  finditer() instead findall() for the same above

Comment: @Dip See https://ideone.com/MHTbrH

Comment: can we do with finditer() function because i want the span for MatchObject ?

Comment: @Dip You can change it to re.finditer and print the span, see https://ideone.com/aM8Tpk

Comment: Thank you so much i learned a lot.